Average deviation of a set of $10$ random integers between $-5$ and $+5$
I have a rating system. Ratings are integer values from $-5$ to $+5$, thus there are $11$ possible ratings. From the most recent $10$ ratings, I calculate the average deviation of the ratings as follows:

calculate the average rating: sum of last $10$ ratings divided by $10$;
calculate the average deviation: sum of the absolute differences between each rating and the average rating, divided by $10$.

If I were to generate $N$ number of $10$-rating sets, each rating of each set being a random integer value from $-5$ to $+5$, then sum the average deviations of each set together, then divide the sum by $N$, this would give the average deviation (AVD) over $N$ $10$-rating sets. It seems that AVD should converge to some value as $N$ increases to infinity. I wrote a computer program to determine this value by brute force of the computer, and it seems that after several hours the number converges to $2.70526$.
Is there an elegant way to compute this number?

As the distribution is uniform, this is just $\sum_{k=-5}^5\frac { |k|}{11}=\frac {30}{11}=2.\overline{72}$

@lulu This should be an answer!

Note:  the solution I describe below assumes that the population mean ($0$) is used in the computation of the Mean Absolute Deviation.  The OP remarks, however, that this is not what was intended.  Rather, the sample mean is used in each case. Thus what follows differs from the OP's intent.
The distribution in question is uniform, each value has a $\frac 1{11}$ chance of being drawn.  Hence, the mean absolute deviation is given by $$\sum_{k=-5}^5 \frac {|k|}{11}=\frac {30}{11}=2.\overline {72}$$

My question does not ask what is the average of the absolute values of integers from -5 to +5. It asks what is the average deviation of a set of 10 random integer values between -5 and +5. Now you might ask why I'm calculating average deviation instead of standard deviation. I'm not actually sure which would be more appropriate for my application. But in either case, I would like to know if there is an elegant calculation of the answer.

The Mean Absolute Deviation is a perfectly standard thing to measure...there are instances in which it is preferable to the usual standard deviation.    But, since the mean of your sample is $0$, the calculation for it in this case is the one I provided.

I agree that if you take the average of N random integers from -5 to +5, that average would converge to 0 as N increases to infinity.  But for any set of 10 integers, that average can be anywhere from -5 to +5, And the calculation of the average deviation for any set of 10 integers must involve the calculation of the average of those particular 10 integers. Does that not make sense?

No, it doesn't.  Of course, any sample would have its own deviation however computed.  You were asking about the large $N$ limit.  If you have a particular sample, you couldn't just assume $\frac 1{11}$ for the probabilities, you'd have to weight by the relevant percent of each term in the sample.  If you meant something other than the large $N$ limit, you should edit your post to clarify.

I would love to clarify my post, but I'm not sure how.. The program I wrote performs the operations exactly as I have described them in my post. If this program came up with the number 2.727272 as the answer then I might be saying "duh', but it doesn't. It comes up with 2.570526.

You said it came up with $2.70526$ which is a lot closer.  But, in any case, I can't see another way to read the question.  For a given set of $10$ selections, let $a_i$ be the number of times $i$ occurs, for $i\in {-5, -4, \cdots, 4, 5}$.  Then, don't you compute $\frac 1{10}\times \sum_{i=-5}^5 a_i\times |i|$?

Yes, that's how I calculate the average of 10 ratings, which is step 1 in my post. But then there is step 2 to calculate the average deviation.

No, the average should be computed without the absolute value.  Ah, ok, so you do the sum I wrote, only you use $|i-m_A|$ where $m_A$ is the sample mean, not the population mean.  Is that your point?  If so, I suggest:  run the program using the population mean ($0$) to see if you then get $\frac {30}{11}$.   It's not obvious to me what effect using all the sample means has.

Should say:  this is one reason  people prefer the use of the standard variance.  For that, we can easily expand $(i-m_A)^2=i^2-2im_A+m_A^2$ and thereby handle all the different means.  But you can't easily express $|i-m_A|$ in similar fashion.  Even in the case of standard variance, though, the different means would have an effect, since they appear squared so the fact that $m_A$ is as likely as $-m_A$ doesn't cancel let you cancel.

Yes, I agree, and I don't take the absolute value of anything when I calculate the average of the 10 ratings. But in step 2, to calculate the average deviation (also called average absolute deviation) I take the sum of the absolute differences between each rating and the average of the 10 ratings. Do you not agree that is the correct way to calculate the average deviation?

It depends.  For large $N$, I would certainly say you should use the population mean rather than the sample mean, as the population mean is a more accurate estimator of the true mean.  In any case, that's what my calculation assumed.  I'll leave the post up, but make a note that it doesn't accurately reflect your intent.

Surely people have looked at the aggregated effect on MAD of using sample means...I suggest posting your question on Cross Validated, the statistics stack exchange.  If you do post over there, I suggest writing out exactly what computation you perform (as I did in the comments here), lest somebody make the same bad assumption that I made.

What I'm trying to do is to convert my calculation of the average deviation of 10 ratings into a percentage which goes from -100% to +100%. -100% would be if half the ratings were -5 and the other half +5, +100% would be if all 10 ratings were the same, and 0% would be if the 10 ratings were generated by a machine that generated random integers from -5 to +5. And so I got the computer to tell me what average deviation value should correspond to 0%, and the number it comes up with is 2.570526.

Again, in your post you claimed a value of $2.7056$.  I don't know if that was a typo or not, but it was so close to the value I got using the population mean that I assumed that was what you intended.  In any case, I think the problem is clear now, and I agree it will yield a different result.  I suspect people have looked at it, it seems natural enough, but the place to get the benefit of the knowledge would probably be the statistics stack exchange I proposed.

I stress, however: if you post over there, write out the computation you performed in detail, using formulas, not words, wherever possible.  Just to avoid missreadings

Thank you for this conversation. I think I will take your advice.
